# Delete SQL rows from Excel

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, vba

I am trying to use excel macro to delete specific rows from sql table, I have this script to insert and just tweaked it a little to no avail. can some one help out please. here is what im trying

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "DELETE FROM dbo.AssociateInfo" & _
" WHERE (ID, FirstName, LastName, HireDate) " & _
" = (?,?,?,?);"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=BLANK;Initial Catalog=BLANK;User ID=BLANK;Password=BLANK;"
'Skip the header row
iRowNo = 2





With Sheets("Sheet1")
  'Loop until empty cell in FirstName
  Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""

  Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = strSQL

  cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("pID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8, .Cells(iRowNo, 1))
  cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("pFirstName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, .Cells(iRowNo, 2))
  cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("pLastName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, .Cells(iRowNo, 3))
  cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("pHireDate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, .Cells(iRowNo, 4))

  cmd.Execute

  iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
  Loop

  MsgBox "Data Successfully Exported"

End With

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Im thinking I have the delete from script incorrect.

here how it was when I used it for insert

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.AssociateInfo" & _
"(ID, FirstName, LastName, HireDate) " & _
"VALUES (?,?,?,?);"
```

Comment: Missing a space before the `WHERE` keyword. You have `... dbo.AssociateInfoWHERE ...`. It worked for `INSERT` because the table name was followed by a parenthesis rather than a keyword

Comment: Oops my mistake... Getting an error still `An expression of non-Boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.`

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I got it, all you have to do is have the `strSQL` show the correct SQL query

```
strSQL = "DELETE FROM dbo.AssociateInfo WHERE ID = ? AND FirstName = ? AND LastName = ? AND HireDate = ?;"
```